# Update an attribute in a json string with dynamicly created textboxes

Tags: javascript, json, frontend

```js
{
  "Active": true,
  "ID": 0,
  "Name": "Box",
  "children": [
    {
      "Active": true,
      "ID": 1,
      "Name": "glas",
      "children": [
        {
          "Active": true,
          "ID": 1,
          "size": "600",
          "Name": "glas",
          "children": [
            {
              "Active": true,
              "ID": 1,
              "Name": "box"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Active": true,
          "ID": 100,
          "Name": "bottle"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My javascript application receives following json string

```
{
  "Active": true,
  "ID": 0,
  "Name": "Box",
  "children": [
    {
      "Active": true,
      "ID": 1,
      "Name": "glas",
      "children": [
        {
          "Active": true,
          "ID": 1,
          "size": "600",
          "Name": "glas",
          "children": [
            {
              "Active": true,
              "ID": 1,
              "Name": "box"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Active": true,
          "ID": 100,
          "Name": "bottle"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For every main object with its attributes I want to create a textbox und bind it (or be able update it).

I manage to create for every property a textbox. But I fail to update the json string when i edit the textbox.I left out the creation the textboxes since I dont want to infleunce your answers.

Keep in mind that I dont have a fixed structure and the properties of the objects are also variable.

Is there a way to accomplish this with normal javascript libs?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code-writing service was recently shut down. You'll have to try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Look into how & why you want to separate your UI from your data model using (any of a dozen) front-end MVC frameworks - Angular2, React, Knockout, Vue, etc. 
Any of these will help w/the process of binding data to your UI, but there are good & less-good ways to do that.

Text boxes in the UI shouldn't know or care what data structure you have - they should (generally) only know how/where to display themselves, and how to collect & pass on user input. That said, most of these frameworks involve creating templates that *could* tightly couple your UI elements to the data, depending which you use & what approach you take.

Updating the data model (your collection of objects) should ideally happen independently of however many boxes you have on screen. The # of text boxes should *reflect* what your data looks like - not the other way around, which is what it sounds like you're doing.

2) Don't try to manipulate the JSON directly, which is what it sounds like you're doing.

When you get the JSON (from a file or web service/API call, etc), parse it into an array to use locally.
Something like `var objectArray = JSON.parse(theJSONstring)` ... If you're using an MVC framework, this array would likely be a component property.

When the UI gets some input and calls some function (from an event listener or from button binding, etc) to add/remove an object, pass that info through the respective functions to add or remove the object to/from the local array (and then update the UI accordingly to reflect the new array values).

When you want to save the whole thing, use `JSON.stringify(objectArray)` on the entire array and save it or output it wherever. No need to manipulate the JSON string directly.

3) Also looks like you need to standardize how you define & create new `Parent` & `Child` objects and initialize whatever properties you want them to have.

Your data structure can vary in terms of how many children there are, or what properties a `Parent` has vs. a `Child`, but it's still just "a `Parent` object with an array of `Child` objects". What should each of those objects have or be able to do in terms of properties & functionality? Do you have multiple varieties of objects based on those basic templates?

Currently you have several objects w/identical IDs, including parent/children w/the same ID. This makes an ID fairly pointless. So give some more thought to your data model and how it should be structured.

Once you've done that, instead of just creating an array from JSON directly, you could loop through the JSON to properly create new `Parent` or `Child` objects with the correct respective properties, and then store those in an array. Add/remove the `Parent` and `Child` instances, update the UI accordingly to display them however you need to, and when you're all done, you can write the array out to JSON.